# MySQL UNION ALL with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to work out the most efficient query to put data from two tables into one set of results and left join the user data to it. I need help with the syntax for the query. I have put together the below but it's not quite right.

```
$query_chat = sprintf("SELECT comment_id, user_id, comment, timestamp FROM activity 
UNION ALL
SELECT comment_id, user_id, comment, timestamp FROM comments
LEFT JOIN users.company, users.contact_person, users.email ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
WHERE user_id = %s
ORDER BY timestamp DESC", GetSQLValueString($_GET['comment_id'], "INT"));
```

The syntax is wrong and throws up the below - I am trying to make it efficient by only selecting what I need from the users table.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' users.contact_person, users.email ON users.user_id = comments.user_id WHERE us' at line 4

I have now got to this point below but get Unknown column 'users.company' in 'field list'

```
SELECT
    comments.comment_id, comments.user_id, comments.comment,
    comments.timestamp,
    users.company, users.contact_person, users.email
FROM
    comments
UNION ALL
SELECT
    activity.comment_id, activity.user_id, activity.comment,
    activity.timestamp, 
    users.company, users.contact_person, users.email
FROM
    activity
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
WHERE
comments.comment_id = 69 ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not quite right"? Does it work? What is the problem with the syntax? Also, why are you left-joining users to comments? If a comment exists, should it not always have a user? Or can a comment be made with a null `comments.user_id`?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' users.contact_person, users.email ON users.user_id = comments.user_id WHERE us' at line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally got there with the below, appreciate the direction halfer

```
SELECT
    comments.*, users.company, users.contact_person, users.email
    FROM
        comments
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
    WHERE
        comment_id = %s
UNION ALL
SELECT activity.*, users.company, users.contact_person, users.email
    FROM
        activity
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = activity.user_id
    WHERE
        comment_id = %s
ORDER BY
    timestamp ASC
```

Comment: Great! I've added some suggested formatting, which will make it clearer its a `UNION` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem:

```
LEFT JOIN
    users.company, users.contact_person, users.email
    ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
```

The syntax is:

```
LEFT JOIN (table) ON (join-clause)
```

So, in your case, I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT
    comments.comment_id, comments.user_id, comments.comment,
    comments.timestamp,
    users.company, users.contact_person, users.email
FROM
    comments
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
WHERE
    users.user_id = %s
;
```

As you can see, when using a `JOIN`, the columns come first (from all tables) and then the tables come next, with their corresponding `JOIN` clauses.

---

Update: in reply to your update, you have two options. You can do this (which you are closest to):

```
SELECT
    (users joined to activity)
UNION
    (users joined to comments)
```

You already know how to do the (expressions) above - see the earlier part of my answer. Or, you can do things this way:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM activity UNION SELECT * FROM comments) user_actions
    LEFT JOIN users ON (users.user_id = user_actions.user_id)
```

Note that in both examples cases in this update, I am offering *pseudocode*<sup>1</sup> - you need to fill in the blanks. You'll find that the skill of taking a generalised example (say from a manual) and applying to your own use case is something that happens a great deal in computer science, so you should practice this as often as possible.

<sup>1</sup> That said, the second version containing the sub-query is done except for changing the columns to fetch - so you are probably 95% of the way there!

Comment: it was just to illustrate that I only wanted those three columns from the users table if that's even poss. My original query was

Comment: SELECT comment_id, user_id, comment, timestamp FROM activity 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT comment_id, user_id, comment, timestamp FROM comments
 LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC

Comment: which throws up Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Excellent! That means you are most of the way there. Just clarify that reference to which table you mean here, and you are done! (Since they are joined, it doesn't matter which you choose - I've amended my answer to read `users` here).

Comment: The query doesn't have any syntax errors but I am missing the data from the activity column that I was trying to do a union all on: SELECT comment_id, user_id, comment, timestamp FROM activity

Comment: Alright, so add that back in via a `UNION ALL`? I didn't add that into my example, since the syntax of that seemed to be okay.

Comment: I tried adding a UNION ALL back in but I get Unknown column 'users.company' in 'field list'

Comment: Right, that is to be expected. The purpose of a `UNION` is to join two or more queries that would work on their own. The simplest way to fix that now is to join `comments` to `users` in the first `SELECT` - but note that your join in the second clause won't work, as you need there to join `users` to `activity`, not to `users`.

Comment: Aside: let me comment on your broad approach, as it is often the _manner of asking questions_ that determines whether a problem can be solved. Let us assume I was asking the original question. I would first have reached for the manual to find that my `LEFT JOIN` syntax does not work. Now, suppose I had done some research, decided finally to ask for help here, and set out the above question. When someone offers assistance, it is best to use their help as a starting point to further research, and not necessarily expecting code that will work verbatim.

Comment: So, your solution is to get the two halves of the query working on their own, each joining `users` to either `activity` or `comments`. Once you have done that, if the query column lists are compatible, you will be able to union them. Give it a go? It will be excellent practice!

Comment: Appreciate your help halfer. Was getting frustrated and impatient so apologies for the dupe post